# The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [3.0.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version

Tags: ios, app-store

I am uploading my IPA file to app store and it throw me below error:

> ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [3.0.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [3.0.1]."

Below is my config for IOS:

```
 "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.test.test.test",
      "buildNumber": "5",
      "icon": "./assets/images/test.png",
      "config": {
        "googleSignIn": {
          "reservedClientId": ""
        }
      },
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Your current location will be displayed on the map and used for directions, nearby search results, and estimated travel times.",
        "CFBundleShortVersionString":"3.0.3",
        "CFBundleIdentifier": "com.test.test.test"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like app store was picking up the version from my package.json file which had a version key.I updated it to 4.0.0 and it worked successfully.Some issue with the expo cli I guess.

Answer (score 7):

If an app version[3.0.3] is already approved then you have **increase the version number[3.0.4]**. If you **increase the build number** you will get the **same error**.

Comment: Can you please try with version 4.0 and build 1

Comment: Got this error now.I dont think my "CFBundleShortVersionString" is working.Redundant Binary Upload. You’ve already uploaded a build with build number '1' for version number '3.0.0'. Make sure you increment the build string before you upload your app to iTunes Connect.

Comment: You got this error after upgrading version to 4.0 and build to 1.

Comment: Your previous version 3.0.1 is approved. That version is live ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to reject the build in iTunesConnect and submit a [new build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n64zF.png)
 with a higher build number

Comment: worked for me I had a approved build of 1.0, but when I try to upload 1.1 it gave error. Then I rejected the approved app and uploaded 1.1 then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of approved app build is higher that you trying to push.

1. go to appStoreConnect
2. check build that was approved (ax example 34)
3. set in project configuration same build+1 (35)
4. cleanup XCode Build Caches and do brand new archive :)

Comment: Thank you! This is the actual answer!
`App.xcodproj > build settings > Marketing Version`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the buildNumber and make it higher than 5.

Answer (score 0):

I created version in app store connect "1.0".
Publish new version "1.0.1", and this error  is showing.

"1.0" = "1.0".1

I made 1.1.1 > 1.0 and it success uploaded.